# How to read the count of the cells with data with non "no-data" values ,in QGis?

Tags: qgis, python, raster, qgis-plugins

How to read the count of the cells with data with non "no-data" values ,in QGis

Comment: You want to count what? Please specify what you what to do.

Comment: Can you use the edit button beneath your Question to revise it with more details and background about what you are trying to do, please?

Comment: The tags make it clear that a QGIS method to return the count of non-null cells in a raster is desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the processing framework there is a 'Raster layer statistic' tool that among others returns the number of no-data cells.

Processing toolbox:

[image]

Result:

[image]

If you want to see the no-data value of the grid look in Properties:
[image]

Comment: Not working in QGIS 3.22.4

Comment: Neither QGIS 3.24

Answer (score 0):

The **Raster Layer Unique Values Report** algorithm gives you the number of NoData cells. (Tested on QGIS 3.32)

[image: Raster Layer Unique Values Report]

[image: Report with nondata]